# Asynchronous writing to a file only through the browser

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rpc

The device records events in the system and stores them. With an RPC request, I can get all the events. But I need to save them to a file.

I created a button to export all events to the user's computer. With rpc requests, I get a response from the device (asynchronously). In portions of ~ 250 messages, and each portion I have to write to a file.

With input, I allow the file to be modified on the client side. However, I don't understand what tools and APIs I can use. For example, Blob files do not solve my problem. Blobs are immutable. Also, I don't have to store the entire file in the browser before downloading. The file must be guessable on the client side.

Comment: Users can download files if they want, but you can't freely write files in the background for obvious security reasons. Browsers will never allow JS to do that.

Comment: yes, I understand, but then what methods can there be? considering that I cannot take data from the server, that is, all operations need to be done on the client side?

Comment: A download link, there's only that